# I'm getting an error in react-firebaseui in Next.js project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am trying to build a firebase auth page for my Next.js project and get the following error:

```
./node_modules/firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules.
```

I found a github [issue page](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5393) but didn't understand what I should actually do to solve the problem

Comment: Had you look at this: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#import-styles-from-node_modules ?